# Chrome 71 force-device-scale-factor < 1 not working

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, teamcity

After updating Google Chrome to version 71, --force-device-scale-factor less than 1 (--force-device-scale-factor=0.5) has stopped working.

Does anyone know how to fix it, or do you have an alternative?

Comment: What's the purpose of setting this to 0.5?

Comment: It is some bigger thing,  ecause also viewport settings for page doesn't work in this version (or at least in mobile version for Android).